# PHP Api Receiving JSON data

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to make an API with PHP and JSON, however I am stuck on extracting the JSON on the receiving/API side of the request.

So I am doing this on the **client** end of my transaction:

```
$data = array("test" => "test");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://..../api/v1/functions?  key=TPO4X2yCobCJ633&aid=9&action=add');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$return = curl_exec($ch);
```

But how do I receive and extract the `POST`ed data on the **server** (receiving) side of the transaction (inside my API)?

Summary:

What i mean is i have a client that is sending a JSON file to the API now i what i don't understand is how can i get the API side to see and extract/see the data

Comment: See what is in `$return`. That will be your resulting json string. `var_dump($return)`. Add the output to the code to help you out further.

Comment: also don't forget to close curl = `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: Well, then you make your scripts on the server side that reads in the query strings using $_POST just like processing an HTML form. Then use json_encode to convert array to JSON string.

Comment: Are you handling the server side of the API now? Are you trying to process the data that was posted to the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the receiving side you need to read from the [PHP input stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), then decode:

```
<?php

// read the incoming POST body (the JSON)
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

// decode/unserialize it back into a PHP data structure
$data = json_decode($input);

// $data is now the same thing it was line 1 of your given sample code
```

If you wanted to be more succinct, you could obviously just nest those calls:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: You sir are awesome!

Comment: Nah, just been through the experience of learning that before. :) Happy coding!